# How to start darkice on boot using a systemd service (or alternatives)

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to start **darkice** each time the raspberry pi is booted.

I created a file `/etc/systemd/darkice.service` like this

```
description = darkice_radio_streamer

After = multi-user.target

[Service]
#Type=simple
Type = Idle
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi 
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sh /home/pi/startup.sh
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
Restart=always
User=root
Group=root
LimitNOFILE=10240
LimitFSIZE=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=multi.target
```

The startup.sh file has one line

```
/usr/bin/darkice -c /home/pi/darkice_current.cfg
```

I enabled the service using

```
sudo systemctl enable darkice
```

When logged in as the "pi" user via SSH, I can start the service like this

```
sudo systemctl start darkice
```

But when I restart the pi using

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

The service doesn't start.

```
sudo systemctl status darkice
```

Returns

ESCOD
● darkice.service
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/darkice.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled
Active: inactive (dead)

I can now type

```
sudo systemctl start darkice
```

and the service starts.

I tried also starting the service as User/Group pi but that didn't help.

- How can I start the service on boot without having to start it manually after each reboot?
- Is there some other way I could start it?

Comment: what if you change `After = multi-user.target` to `After=network.target` - note: I assume those first two lines are actually after `[unit]` which you haven't shown in your question) - also, personally, I wouldn't run `darkice` as root, there shouldn't be any need to do so

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried `After=network.target` earlier, that did not change anything. Regarding running as root: If I start darkice as a pi user (with sudo rights) it asks for my password to sudo itself.. - my guess is that is has something to do with accessing the audio. Since the pi's only job is to stream the audio via darkice, I'm not too worried about running it as root.

Comment: I gather you've shown the complete output of `systemctl status darkice` - no actual errors shown? Is there any useful logs in any `/var/log` file to indicate what the issue is? Just to test, can you put a `sleep 30` above `/usr/bin/darkice -c /home/pi/darkice_current.cfg` in the shell script

Comment: Thanks, I did also try a sleep command (of 15 seconds) in the sh file before posting here without success. There are 5 warnings in the `systemctl status darkice`, (about blank lines and sections) but the script runs when started manually. The device is not local and I can currently not access it, I'll try to add these the next time I get access.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that icecast isn't started properly directly after boot.
Starting it before darkice is needed.

So the startup.sh needs to look like this

```
/etc/init.d/icecast2 start
/usr/bin/darkice -c /home/pi/darkice_current.cfg
```

See: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=159760